# Missing records during incremental ETL with long running updates/inserts on temporal tables

Tags: sql-server, etl, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2017, temporal-tables

We use standard approach when loading data from temporal tables - getting all the changes that happened after the last load by comparing period start column value with the latest load timestamp.

As per [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) (the same apply both for updates and deletes also)

> INSERTS: On an INSERT, the system sets the value for the SysStartTime
> column to the begin time of the current transaction (in the UTC time
> zone) based on the system clock and assigns the value for the
> SysEndTime column to the maximum value of 9999-12-31. This marks the
> row as open.

Let's assume that we start some long running transaction at `2019-12-02 15:27:00`, for example

```
BEGIN TRAN;
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:03:00';
    
    UPDATE a
    SET account_balance = 999
    FROM dbo.accounts AS a
    WHERE a.id= 'XXXXX'
COMMIT;
```

and our last load was at `2019-12-02 15:26:00`. So when we run the ETL, it will get all modified changes:

`SELECT * FROM dbo.accounts WHERE SysSstart > '2019-12-02 15:26:00'`

Let's assume the ETL finished at `2019-12-02 15:28:00` and saved the value.

As we had delay for 3 minutes, then UPDATE finished at `2019-12-02 15:30:00`, but `SysStart` column value will be `2019-12-02 15:27:00` as it was at the beginning of the update transaction. So if we run the ETL again, records updated in this transaction will not be loaded as they will not match `SysSstart > '2019-12-02 15:28:00'` predicate.

How to handle such situation?

Comment: @lachicazul makes a good point - use the end not the start date as your high water mark, and exclude end dates of `9999-12-31`. In the case you state above, what will happen is that the open transaction will not be picked up by the first run, but it will be picked up the second run.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a better solution but right now I get these 2 simple ideas (because it seems you just need to know when the last update occurs):

1. Add a LoadDateTime to your dbo.accounts and use it in your query SELECT * FROM dbo.accounts WHERE **LoadDateTime** > '2019-12-02 15:26:00'
2. Save when the ETL starts and not when it ends